# Is there any simple implementation or tutorial to implement RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to port my existing project to material design but am unable to understand the implementation of RecyclerView. My old code uses a ListView but I want GMail app like lists.

I have read tons of tutorials but most of them either skip the `ItemDecoration` part or the `ClickListener` part. Different tutorials have entirely different implementations and code varies to the point that I am unable to understand where to put what.

I am struggling in the following, which I compiled by reading various tutorials:

1. Adapter: My adapter code is the following:

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private final Context mContext;
   private List<String> mData1, mData2;

   public MyAdapter(Context mContext, String[] data1,String[] data2) {
   this.mContext = mContext;
   if (data1 != null)
       mData1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1));
   else mData1 = new ArrayList<String>();

   if (data2 != null)
       mData2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data2));
   else mData2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   public void add(String s,int position) {
   position = position == -1 ? getItemCount()  : position;
   mData1.add(position,s);

   notifyItemInserted(position);
   }

   public void remove(int position){
   if (position < getItemCount()  ) {
       mData1.remove(position);
       notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }
   }


   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
   View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,viewGroup,false);

   return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
   myViewHolder.tv1.setText(mData1.get(position));
   myViewHolder.tv2.setText(mData2.get(position));

   myViewHolder.setClickListener(new MyViewHolder.ClickListener()
   {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"The selected position is: "+ pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
     });




     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
     return mData1.size();
     }

     public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
   {
   protected TextView tv1;
   protected TextView tv2;
   ClickListener clickListener;



   public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
       tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);


   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   }

   public void onClick(View v, int pos)
   {
       clickListener.onClick(v,getPosition());

   }

   public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener)
   {
       this.clickListener = clickListener;
   }


   public interface ClickListener
   {
       public void onClick(View v,int pos);

   }
   }
   }
   ```
2. The `ItemDecoration` is copied from here: https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e. But do I really need such a large class just to put simple dividers between list items? What if I wanted to implement the code on my own?
3. I still cannot figure out the `OnClickListener`. For a start, the I want a simple `OnClickListener` just like `ListView.OnClickListener`. The current `OnClickListener` was compiled from a tutorial but does not work.

Full code here: https://github.com/pauldmps/MaterialDesign/

Comment: A large class that does a small thing! I have no problem in writing large classes but this was copy pasted as it is & I have no clue what it actually does. I would rather implement in on my own.

Comment: Look up, and implement the ViewHolder pattern correctly, and in a way that suits your needs.

Comment: @ShantanuPaul do note that you are adding and removing only mdata1, but when you call  onBindViewHolder, you are using both mdata1 and mdata2. this would be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **RecyclerView Adapter Example:**

1. Adapter issue can be solved using below code:

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>         
   {

   private final Context mContext;
   private List<String> mData1, mData2;

   public MyAdapter(Context mContext, String[] data1, String[] data2) {
   this.mContext = mContext;
   if (data1 != null)
       mData1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1));
   else
       mData1 = new ArrayList<String>();

   if (data2 != null)
       mData2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data2));
   else
       mData2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   public void add(String s, int position) {
   position = position == -1 ? getItemCount() : position;
   mData1.add(position, s);

   notifyItemInserted(position);
   }

   public void remove(int position) {
   if (position < getItemCount()) {
       mData1.remove(position);
       notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }
   }

   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
   View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

   return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
       myViewHolder.tv1.setText(mData1.get(position));
   myViewHolder.tv2.setText(mData2.get(position));
   myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           clickListener.onClick(v, position);
       }
   });
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
   return mData1.size();
   }

   ClickListener clickListener;

   public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
   this.clickListener = clickListener;
   }

   public interface ClickListener {
   public void onClick(View v, int pos);

   }

   public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   protected TextView tv1;
   protected TextView tv2;

   public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
       tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

   }

   }
   }
   ```

Usage is as below:

```
MyAdapter adapter=....;
adapter.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int pos) {
            // do whatever you want
        }
    });
```

2. There is not any Simple way to do that. But i would suggest you one workaround for this. Add below view as a divider at the bottom inside your `list_item.xml`.

   ```
    <View
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0.5dip" 
   android:background="@color/light_gray"/>
   ```
3. Item click listener is also resolved in point no. 1 above.

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for Simple Implementation of RecyclerView using a Simple Library

Add this line in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.hereshem.lib:awesomelib:2.0.1'
```

Create RecyclerView Layout in Activity with

```
<com.hereshem.lib.recycler.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create a ViewHolder by passing the class it suppports

```
public static class EVHolder extends MyViewHolder<Events> {
    TextView date, title, summary;
    public EVHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        summary = v.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(Events c) {
        date.setText(c.date);
        title.setText(c.title);
        summary.setText(c.summary);
    }
}
```

Create Items List variable and adapters with very few lines

```
List<Events> items = new ArrayList<>();
MyRecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, items, EVHolder.class, R.layout.row_event);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ClickListener can be added with folllowing line

```
recycler.setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recycler Item Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

More example can be found [here](https://github.com/hereshem/Easy-RecyclerView-Library)

Hope this helps :)