# SetAdapter method for HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, adapter, horizontalscrollview

i am working with android.In android,I created one **HorizontalScrollView** and for the **HorizontalScrollView** i created simple adapter but when i am using **set adapter** method with HorizontalScrollView than i am getting error that ***The method setAdapter(SimpleAdapter) is undefined for the type HorizontalScrollView***.so can you tell me which method i should use at the place of setadapter.

```
SimpleAdapter videoadapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SearchData.this, VideoDataList,
                R.layout.video_list, new String[]
                        {   
                        TAG_Title
                         }, new int[] { 
                        R.id.textView1 });
        VideoDatalist.setAdapter(videoadapter);
```

here ***VideoDataList*** is the object of HorizontalScrollView

Comment: There is nothing called setadapter for horizontalScrollView.. Its not a listview.. It doesnt have the concept of recycling, in order to have horizontal listview concept you can use RecycleView which is introduced recently

Comment: use this link for reference to implement horizontal view http://stackoverflow.com/a/29052640/1576416