# GridView with only SingleRow and Multiple Column

Tags: android, gridview

I searched a lot and found many solution but no one fit in my case. actually i am working for Smart TV application. I used HorizontalListView but it not take foucs . but when i use GridView then focus is handled by GridView itself. Then my requirment is for making gridview single row and mutiple column.

Nitin Tyagi

Comment: I think in Grid View , this is not possible. You can try RecyclerView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html .

Comment: @Sajal in RecylerView is it possible of HorizontalScrolling for item ?

Comment: @nitintyagi yes you should use recycler view with horizontal orientation

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29052640/1576416

Comment: yes. like this -- recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku can you please give me any link where i can see some sample related to this.

Comment: @Sajal  i have implemented RecylerView sucessfully but item inside recyler view not getting foucs .I have already told that i am working on Smart TV and there is no touch event . all the event is handled by keydown and keyup. So in my layout xml my recyler is below of some view then please tell me how can i get focus on first item of RecylerView.

Comment: @Sajal thanks fro suggesting . it resolved my problem. Please put this as a answer then i would accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recycler View is like listview but in both orientation i.e. you can have horizontal listview as well as vertical listview.
For this case(horizontal listview), you can make recyclerview horizontal like this -

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: Please add some text to describe why this addresses the problem. I see the answer works, but people visiting this later via Google, etc, would appreciate more information about what you have done, I think.