# android:entries in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have used `listview` with entries attribute like below :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/fi"/>
```

Now i am converting it to `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I want to know whether we have `android:entries` attribute in `RecyclerView`? Or any other attribute instead of entries?

Comment: there is no option  because recyclerview have no base default itemxml file .you must create adpter for that

Comment: no option? and how `ListView` makes this? see the sources of `ListView` then, [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#161) for example

Comment: @pskink thnks for valuable comment, so there is no way other than creating adapter? We can not assign item values from xml, right?

Comment: see the source i linked, `ListView` gest the values from xml resource file like this: `a.getTextArray(R.styleable.ListView_entries);`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As correctly explained in the other answers there isn't an attribute to fill the RecyclerView from xml. However using the [Android Databinding](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html) you can create a similar attribute quite easily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:entries="@{@stringArray/fi}"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</layout>
```

Here the binding adapter definition:

```
import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;

public class RecyclerViewBindings {

    @BindingAdapter("entries")
    public static void entries(RecyclerView recyclerView, String[] array) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleArrayAdapter(array));
    }

    static class SimpleArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleHolder> {

        private final String[] mArray;

        public SimpleArrayAdapter(String[] array) {
            mArray = array;
        }

        @Override
        public SimpleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            final View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            return new SimpleHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mTextView.setText(mArray[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mArray.length;
        }
    }

    static class SimpleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView mTextView;

        public SimpleHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to use the `DataBindingUtil` methods for inflate the layout.

Inflate inside an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_main);
}
```

Inflate inside a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ContentMainBinding bindings = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.content_main, container, false);
    return bindings.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: This is new information for me, you made a hopeless thread into a very useful one with this answer alone! bravo. What I wan to know is how the BindingAdapter linked to our particular recycler view?

Comment: @Riccardo : No adapter attached; skipping layout. Getting this error

Comment: You need to use the Databinding methods to inflate the view. I'll update my  answer

Answer (score 5):

> **No. There is no such directly available attribute in `RecyclerView`.** You have to do it from java code programatically using `LayoutManager` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052640/1576416).

**REASON:**
As we know, `RecyclerView` won't inflate until we set a `LayoutManager` to it. Also, `LayoutManager` is necessary to inflate individual item views of `RecyclerView`.  These individual item views are retrieved from the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. So, until you set both the `LayoutManager` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` to `RecyclerView`, you can't use `RecyclerView`.

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid this is not possible out of the box, you can extend the RecyclerView and define your own custom attribute which accepts a string array, then you would populate your RecyclerView Adapter with these values.

Check this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Answer (score -1):

No,In android, Recyclerview doesn't hold android:entries or like attributes.
RecyclerView is successor of listview but still missing entries attribute and onclicklistener

here is android official documentation link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

This site also describes about the android:entries attribute.

http://androidride.com/easiest-way-make-listview-android/