# Using a BindingAdapter with a string-array from the resources

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources, android-databinding

I have an *almost* simple idea: I want to generate an Adapter for a spinner with the data binding API and an BindingAdapter. Here is the XML I want to use:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:value="@{address.country}"
    app:data="@{@array/countries}"
    app:keys="@{@array/iso_3166_2}"/>
```

Address here is a simple class which has a field called `country` which is a String and will contain a ISO-3166-2 String. To keep it simple the values will be "DE" or "US".

This here is my simplified **`arrays.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="iso_3166_2">
        <item>DE</item>
        <item>US</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="countries">
        <item>@string/country_DE</item>
        <item>@string/country_US</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

For the binding I wrote this BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"value", "data", "keys"})
public static void generateAdapter(Spinner spinner,
                                   String value,
                                   @ArrayRes int data,
                                   @ArrayRes int keys) {

}
```

When I try to compile the code I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. countries is missing it
>   file:path/to/the/spinner-above.xml
>   loc:95:31 - 95:39
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Line 95 of my xml is this line: `app:value="@{address.country}"`

**Do you see what I am doing wrong?**

By the way I am not sure about the annotations related with the array resources is that correct? I find not way to limit it to a string array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can get it by refering `stringArray` instead of `array`. Here is what i have done with recyclerView to get value from resources and it is working perfectly, it might help you also.

in string.xml

```
<string-array name="myItems">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
    <item>Item 6</item>
</string-array>
```

in layout.xml

```
app:entries="@{@stringArray/fi}"
```

in your case it can be `app:data="@{@stringArray/countries}"` or `app:keys="@{@stringArray/iso_3166_2}"`.

and in binding method

```
@BindingAdapter({"entries"})
public static void entries(RecyclerView recyclerView, String[] array) {
    //get all values in array[] variable.
}
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892253/androidentries-in-recyclerview) for more.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access other resource type in databinding layout file, see the source

```
    public String toJava() {
        final String context = "getRoot().getContext()";
        final String viewName = requiresView() ? LayoutBinderWriterKt.getFieldName(mTarget) :
                "getRoot()";
        final String resources = viewName + ".getResources()";
        final String resourceName = mPackage + "R." + getResourceObject() + "." + mResourceId;
        if ("anim".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(" + context + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("animator".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(" + context + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("bool".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getBoolean(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("color".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.databinding.DynamicUtil.getColorFromResource(" + viewName + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("colorStateList".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.databinding.DynamicUtil.getColorStateListFromResource(" + viewName + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("dimen".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getDimension(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("dimenOffset".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getDimensionPixelOffset(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("dimenSize".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getDimensionPixelSize(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("drawable".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.databinding.DynamicUtil.getDrawableFromResource(" + viewName + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("fraction".equals(mResourceType)) {
            String base = getChildCode(0, "1");
            String pbase = getChildCode(1, "1");
            return resources + ".getFraction(" + resourceName + ", " + base + ", " + pbase +
                    ")";
        }
        if ("id".equals(mResourceType)) return resourceName;
        if ("intArray".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getIntArray(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("integer".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getInteger(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("interpolator".equals(mResourceType))  return "android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(" + context + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("layout".equals(mResourceType)) return resourceName;
        if ("plurals".equals(mResourceType)) {
            if (getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                return resourceName;
            } else {
                return makeParameterCall(resources, resourceName, "getQuantityString");
            }
        }
        if ("stateListAnimator".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(" + context + ", " + resourceName + ")";
        if ("string".equals(mResourceType)) return makeParameterCall(resources, resourceName, "getString");
        if ("stringArray".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".getStringArray(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("transition".equals(mResourceType)) return "android.transition.TransitionInflater.from(" + context + ").inflateTransition(" + resourceName + ")";
        if ("typedArray".equals(mResourceType)) return resources + ".obtainTypedArray(" + resourceName + ")";
        final String property = Character.toUpperCase(mResourceType.charAt(0)) +
                mResourceType.substring(1);
        return resources + ".get" + property + "(" + resourceName + ")";

    }
```