# Using a BindingAdapter with a string-array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, androidx, android-binding-adapter

I have the following BindingAdapter:

```java
@BindingAdapter("entries")
fun setEntries(view: Spinner, entries: Array<String>) {
    // Do something
}
```

And on my XML file:

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:entries="@{@stringArray/my_string_array}"/>
```

But when building, I get an error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:entries' with parameter type java.lang.String[] on android.widget.Spinner.
```

I have followed the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899942/using-a-bindingadapter-with-a-string-array-from-the-resources) question, but what would be the Kotlin equivalent for `String[]` in this case?

Or, alternatively, can I pass the actual `resource id` instead of a String array to the Binding Adapter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error won't be reproduced with the code provided, because it was in the second parameter, which I omitted naively thinking it was unrelated to the problem.

The actual code was:

```java
@BindingAdapter("entries", "hint", requireAll = false)
fun setHintAdapter(view: Spinner, entries: Array<String>, @StringRes hintRes: Int?) {

    val hint = hintRes?.run {
        try {
            MainAct.i.getString(this)
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            null
        }
    } ?: ""

    val layout = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

    view.adapter = HintAdapter(hint, view.context, layout, entries)
}
```

And the XML:

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:entries="@{@stringArray/my_string_array}"
    app:hint="@{@string/some_string}"/>
```

The error is completely unrelated to `app:entries`, it's in `app:hint`. I'm providing a `String` and expecting an `Int` (Well, a StringRes).

Changing it to:

```java
@BindingAdapter("entries", "hint", requireAll = false)
fun setHintAdapter(view: Spinner, entries: Array<String>, hint: String) {

    val layout = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

    view.adapter = HintAdapter(hint, view.context, layout, entries)
}
```

Fixes it.