# android: Use Color Array in XML

Tags: android, arrays, xml

As I have seen many post there is way to get **String** Array from XML and bind directly to **`RecyclerView`** or any other control like **Spinner**.

Especially in [Android Databinding](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html) **String Array** binding with **RecylerView** using `app:entries="@{@stringArray/fi}` [like:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276174/1318946)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:entries="@{@stringArray/fi}"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</layout>
```

Is there any way to do it for **color array?**

Answer (score 0):

there is no such attribute available in recyclerview. check out this answer for details--
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276174/5439549