# access integer array using DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to create `RecyclerView` with use of DataBinding for Integer data, i have already tried with String data by declaring `string-array` in `string.xml`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276174/3134215) is answer from where i have taken reference.

Now i am trying to implement it with `integer-array` but not able to access it from xml.

Here is my integer.xml

```
<integer-array name="hours">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</integer-array>
```

here is my xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:entries="@{@integerArray/hours}">
```

and my custom binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("entries")
public static void entries(RecyclerView recyclerView, Integer[] array) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleArrayAdapter(array));
}
```

But it is showing me error `line 1:0 token recognition error at: '@integerArray/'`

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. hours is missing
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution from [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) itself, i was doing silly mistake. It should be `intArray` instead of `integerArray`, and in `BindingAdapter` it should be `int[]`

```
app:entries="@{@intArray/hours}"
```

and adapter should be

```
@BindingAdapter("entries")
public static void entries(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] array) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleArrayAdapter(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Here I want to share the similar solution for binding image from `integer-array` `Drawable` resource.

**My `integer-array` resource of `Drawable`**:

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="platform_images">
        <item>@drawable/android</item>
        <item>@drawable/iphone</item>
        <item>@drawable/windows</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

**My `BindingAdapter` function:**

```
object DataBindingUtil {
    @BindingAdapter("imageIndex", "images")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, imageIndex: Int, images: TypedArray) {
        imageView.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(imageIndex, 0))
    }
}
```

**My `ImageView`:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/android"
    app:imageIndex="@{2}"
    app:images="@{@typedArray/platform_images}" />
```