# Dynamically populating a LinearLayout when using data binding includes

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I have a ViewModel `Group`, that contains a varying number of child ViewModels, `Item`s. It also has list of whether these items should be visible, and looks similar to this:

```
class Group(
    val items: List<Item>
) : ViewModel() {

  val visibleItems = List(items.size) { ObservableBoolean(false) }

}
```

My layout then binds and displays the `Item`s, as well as allowing their visibility to be toggled by other areas of the app:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <include
            layout="@layout/item"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.visibleItems[0] ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel.items[0]}"
            />

        <include
            layout="@layout/item"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.visibleItems[1] ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel.items[1]}"
            />

        ... etc ...
```

This approach works, but has the downside that the LinearLayout is only capable of displaying as many items as are already defined in the XML.

I want to use something like a `BindingAdapter` to automatically populate the items based on the size of `viewModel.items` (`.visibleItems` is always the same size). I've seen [solutions for a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989287/access-integer-array-using-databinding), but as I have a LinearLayout this isn't too helpful.

Comment: Why don't you replace your `LinearLayout` with `RecyclerView `? by doing this you won't even  need to have hardcode include item.

Comment: Yeah, that's what a colleague suggested @KrishnaSharma. The number of items is <10, usually 2-3, so it seemed overkill. Probably the best bet though, thanks.