# How do I databind an object of the String[] type?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I already know that I can set the types for many other lists, but for `String[]` in particular, I currently am having to set the type as `Object` and cast it later to `String[]`.

Using `String&#91;&#93;` is not accepted either.

e.g.

```
    <data>
        <variable name="example" type="Object" />
    </data>   

    <Linearlayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@{(String[]) example}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking further into the `String[]` type, it seems that it isn't a complete type (no size defined) and it doesn't validate any resources. The only valid collection types that the Android docs mention are in the following example:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String&gt;"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String&gt;"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String&gt;"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>
…
android:text="@{list[index]}"
…
android:text="@{sparse[index]}"
…
android:text="@{map[key]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use stringArray:

```
@{@stringArray/fi}
```

Instead of

```
@{(String[])
```

There are a few examples online which may be helpful: [android:entries in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892253/androidentries-in-recyclerview)

Comment: seems to be a solution if I'm using an array from xml, but I'd like to stick the question to solely addressing `String[]`

Comment: As far as I could see from online examples, including some from StackOverflow, this tag can databind any string[] to your model.

Comment: Yup, it works with the cast; but I'd like to know, since all databinded variables have to be type defined at the top of the .xml file, how I can avoid setting the array to be defined as an `Object`. The solutions in your link are just further abstractions of my provided example for the sake of static xml arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Check this from android site :

[image: Check this from android site]